# Compare two numeric pandas dataframes (x,y) with interpolation before comparison

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to compare two numeric dataframes [x1,y1] and [x2,y2] with different x, using ['x1']

```
import pandas as pd
first = {'x1':[0,3,5],'y1':[0,3,6]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(first,columns=['x1','y1'])
print (df1)
   x1   y1
0   0    0
1   3    3
2   5    6
second = {'x2':[0,2,4,6],'y2':[0,2,4,6]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(second,columns=['x2','y2'])
print (df2)
   x2  y2
0   0   0
1   2   2
2   4   4
3   6   6
```

With x1 value to interpolate in x2 to find corresponding y2. Before comparing y1 with y2, I need to work out:

```
   x2  y2
0   0   0
1   2   2
?   3   ?
2   4   4
?   5   ?
3   6   6
```

Then compare y1 and y2 to find out:

```
   x2  y2 y1 y1>y2?
0   0   0  0
1   2   2  
?   3   3  3 False 
2   4   4
?   5   5  6 True
3   6   6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one column `DataFrame` by [`Series.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.append.html) with remove duplicates by [`Series.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) and sorting by [`Series.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html):

```
df = (df2['x2'].append(df1['x1'], ignore_index=True)
              .drop_duplicates()
              .sort_values()
              .to_frame('x2'))
print (df)
   x2
0   0
1   2
5   3
2   4
6   5
3   6
```

Then is added `y2` by [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join and call [`Series.interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html), added new column `y1` by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and last are compared columns:

```
df = df.merge(df2, how='left') 
df['y2'] = df['y2'].interpolate()
df['y1'] = df['x2'].map(df1.set_index('x1')['y1'])
df['y1>y2'] = df['y1'] > df['y2']
print (df)
   x2   y2   y1  y1>y2
0   0  0.0  0.0  False
1   2  2.0  NaN  False
2   3  3.0  3.0  False
3   4  4.0  NaN  False
4   5  5.0  6.0   True
5   6  6.0  NaN  False
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.  With the line `df['y1'] = df['x2'].map(df1.set_index('x1')['y1'])`, I run into `raise InvalidIndexError('Reindexing only valid with uniquely'
pandas.core.indexes.base.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`. Please could you advise.

Comment: @brompton - Problem are duplicates, so is necessary change `df['y1'] = df['x2'].map(df1.set_index('x1')['y1'])` to `df['y1'] = df['x2'].map(df1.drop_duplicates('x1').set_index('x1')['y1'])`